# null value in if condition and null pointer exception java

Tags: java, exception, pointers, null

I want to do something like below in java.

```
String subject=null,receiver=null,subject_db=null,receiver_db=null,cc=null,cc_db=null;
suject=msg.getSubject();
sub_db=rs.getString("subject");
receiver=msg.getreceiver();
receiver_db=rs.getString("receiver");
cc=msg.getcc();
cc_db=rs.getString("cc"); String foldername;

if((subject.equals(sub_db)) && (receiver.equals(receiver_db)) && (cc.equals(cc_db)))
  foldername="spam";
else
  foldername="Inbox";
```

As you can see here, any of the variables can be `null`. If this happens then it throws me NullPointerException. Is there any way I can do like,
`String s1=null` and `String s2=null` and if I compare `if(s1.equals(s2))` then it returns me `true`... I know above code is not gonna work to achieve this. But how do I do that in some other way ?

I am really sorry if I have failed to explain my problem properly...

I would appreciate any help..

Thank you..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about something like…

```
private boolean nullsOrEquals(string s1, string s2)
{
  if (s1 == null)
    return (s2 == null);

  return s1.equals(s2);
}

if (nullsOrEquals(subject, sub_db) && [etc])
  foldername="spam";
else
  foldername="Inbox";
```

Answer (score 3):

`if((s1 == null && s2 == null) || s1.equals(s2))`

Comment: This should be a comment. No? :p

Comment: Or more precisely, to cover your example and avoid the NPE... `if((s1 == null & s2 == null) || s1.equals(s2))`

Comment: @Elite, Sorry, just joined and can't comment until I get some rep :( Try to help when I can but I'm only able to post answers at the moment.

Comment: Edit the full expression into the answer please

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you want to compare Strings even if they are null.

For that just add a condition in the if statement like:

```
if((string1 == null && string2==null) || string1.equals(s2))
{
//Your code
}
```

Comment: Thanks all for your response..Finally I ddid it like.                       private static boolean       nullsOrEquals(String s1, String s2)
 {
   if(s1 == null) 
   {
            if(s2 == null) 
            {
               return true;
            }
        return false;
      }

     if(s2 == null)
     {
        return false;
     }

     return s1.equals(s2);
 }